# Obtaining and sending accelorometer data to Mac

Tags: ios, macos, networking, accelerometer

I need to send data from an accelerometer (from my iPhone) to the Mac. I need a way to send this data to the Mac.

The data should be sent in real time. there should not be any delay as such. What is the best method to send data to the Mac.

1.) Is it through bluetooth or over the network ?

2.) I need to know if there are any tutorials/sample code to obtain accelerometers.

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth on iPhone only allows tethering the wifi and peer-to-peer game play with other iPhones   using the GameKit framework.

And if you try to do it via a server and all then I don't think it will be real time by any means..(The lag will be noticeable if you are trying to control something using the accelerometer.)

Answer for this question is the best I could find... [Bluetooth/WiFi between Mac app and iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982340/bluetooth-wifi-between-mac-app-and-ios-app)

hoping this helps you somewhat.. If I find something else will update it here.

Answer (score 1):

For #1 your proximity will determine your choice.  If you can guarantee that the iPhone will be within bluetooth range then you might use bluetooth.  If your Mac has a fixed IP address then you could use the network.  If real-time is the requirement, then it probably needs to be bluetooth.

For #2, the iOS documentation lists sample code for the UIAccelerometer class as: AccelerometerGraph, BubbleLevel, GLGravity and oalTouch.