# GKSession with Mac OS X

Tags: ios, macos, networking, gamekit, core-bluetooth

I'm using GKSession (part of Game Kit) to connect multiple iOS devices together (over bluetooth and/or wifi), send data, etc which all works fine and I'm happy with it.

I was thinking though, it would be cool to have a Mac OS X app that could connect to the iOS devices as well, share data and so on.

GKSession sadly doesn't seem to be part of Game Kit for Mac OS X (10.8+ obviously). I was wondering is anybody knows of a way to do this or has any ideas.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

GameKit for Mac OSX uses game center over wifi to connect Macs, iPod Touches, iPads, and iPhones to each other through apple's game center servers.

Consult the GameKit Framework reference for Mac OSX for more on how to implement the classes

Comment: I understand that, but that requires a connection to the internet. The part of Game Center in iOS I'm referring to doesn't need an internet connection and uses the local bluetooth and/or wifi.

Comment: @Baza207 ah. According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/7983740/2446155 its impossible. Without using a third party bluetooth framework, I don't believe that there is a way. By the way, I am having an issue with getting GKSession to work for myself on ios devices. Could you help me here?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898417/how-do-i-correctly-setup-a-gksession-bluetooth-on-ios-6-1

Comment: Yeah I thought it wasn't possible natively though Game Center. Unless you go into all the core systems or use a 3rd party library as you said. Shame, I think they missed trick there. Going to leave this open to see if anyone comes up with any bright ideas though. :-D Thanks for the comments.